# Calling a user-defined C# method from within a predicate to an Entity Framework query

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, ado.net

I am using Entity Framework version 6.2.0 targeting the .NET framework version 4.6.1.

I'd like my user-defined function to be a part of the Entity Framework predicate like so:

```
var someValue = ...;

var matchingRecord = context.Records.SingleOrDefaultAsync(
                     rec => My.User.Defined.Function(rec.Property,  someValue) == true);
```

But of course, Entity Framework cannot translate that into a SQL query because there's no equivalent of `My.User.Defined.Function` in T-SQL.

What do I do besides:

1. Using that arcane intermediate language that Entity Framework supports that looks a bit like SQL but isn't.

   OR
2. Using `DbContext.ExecuteCommand()`.

   OR
3. Using ADO.NET's `SqlCommand.ExecuteReader()`.

Is there another option?

Comment: Check if this works for your scenario - [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/how-to-call-custom-database-functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/how-to-call-custom-database-functions)?

Comment: @user1672994 That one maps to a user-defined function in SQL. My question is: I want to call a function that has no representation in SQL. I think there's no way other than to execute the query without the function and then filter on it in the process address space of my own program.

Comment: I don't think you can do that, in linq-to-sql it cannot translate your method into an sql query, which is why it does not work. it uses deferred execution to postpone the execution untill you complete it by calling toList() or something else. but your user defined function cannot be translated into sql, and thus breaks the deferred execution. The only other option, as far as i know, is to complete the query and process the results independently.

Comment: In reality, your sql query is precompiled, then executed at runtime. Your user predefined function cannot do that, cause it's only available at runtime, not on build. Like Glenn said, you have to execute your query, call ToList to get out of the IQueryable, then apply your filter. Unfortunately, you may have some performances troubles doing that, because you're going to load a massive dataset, then filter it.